# Ajax doesn't trigger a change-event on a webkit based browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, jquery-plugins

I have adapted a Jquery plugin to for-fill my needs to send GET requests to servers as a way of "pinging" them.

I've also added some javascript code to add some fancy features like: depending on the changed value in a span that the Jquery plugin changes, it changes the Icon accordingly.

To make it all work essentially, I made so that when Ajax gets a "complete" event, it forces a  "onChange" event to the span, triggering the javascript validation function to change the status icons.

Here is the code of my slightly modified jQuery Plugin:

```
/**
 * ping for jQuery
 * 
 * Adapted by Carroarmato0  (to actually work instead of randomly "pinging" nowhere instead of faking
 *
 * @auth Jessica
 * @link http://www.skiyo.cn/demo/jquery.ping/
 *
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.ping = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ping.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var ping, requestTime, responseTime ;
            var target = $(this);
                        var server = target.html();
                        target.html('<img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading" />');
            function ping() {
                $.ajax({url: 'http://' + server,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    timeout: 30000,
                    beforeSend : function() {
                        requestTime = new Date().getTime();
                    },
                    complete : function() {
                        responseTime = new Date().getTime();
                        ping = Math.abs(requestTime - responseTime);

                                                if (ping > 2000) {
                                                    target.text('niet bereikbaar');
                                                } else {
                                                    target.text(ping + opts.unit);
                                                }

                                                target.change();
                    }
                });
            }
            ping();
            opts.interval != 0 && setInterval(ping,opts.interval * 1000);
        });
    };
    $.fn.ping.defaults = {
        interval: 3,
        unit: 'ms'
    };
})(jQuery);
```

target.change();  is  the code that triggers the "onchange" event in the span:

```
echo "  <td class=\"center\"><span id=\"ping$pingNb\" onChange=\"checkServerIcon(this)\" >" .$server['IP'] . "</span></td>";
```

In Firefox this works, checkServerIcon(this)  gets executed and passes the span object to the function.

```
function checkServerIcon(object) {
    var delayText = object.innerHTML;
    var delay = delayText.substring(0, delayText.length - 2);

    if ( isInteger(delay) ) {
        object.parentNode.previousSibling.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/servers/enable_server.png';

    } else {

        if (delay == "bezig.") {
            object.parentNode.previousSibling.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/servers/search_server.png';
        } else {
            object.parentNode.previousSibling.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/servers/desable_server.png';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try using jQuery's built-in methods for checkServerIcon:

```
$(object).parent().prev().parent().find('img:first').attr({src: 'image-source-here'});
```

There might be some quirks between the browsers that can be fixed by using jQuery's methods instead.

Comment: The thing is, that in de  jQuery plugin, the  target.change()  action doesn't trigger the onChange event at all. (in a Webkit based browser)

Comment: to be more specific:  if  I do the following in a Webkit-based browser,

target.change();
alert("The Monkeys ");

the alert is shown,  but this is never triggered:

onChange="checkServerIcon(this)"


I checked that by adding the following as the first action inside the  checkserverIcon  function:

alert(" are attacking");

And nothing happens.

Comment: try what @Stino said, use jQuery's method for binding onchange >> $('your-span').change(checkServerIcon);

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery change method instaid of javascript's onchange
the target.change() will only trigger jquery's bounded functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

I removed the onchange  event from my span, and instead, gave it a class name:

```
echo "  <td class=\"center\"><span class=\"ping\" id=\"ping$pingNb\">" .$server['IP'] . "</span></td>";
```

Next, I made jQuery add the change event itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span.ping").change(checkServerIcon);
    });
</script>
```

My javascript function had to be rewritten:

```
function checkServerIcon() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var img = tr.find('td>img').first().attr('src');
    var delayText = tr.find('td>span').text();
    var delay = delayText.substring(0, delayText.length - 2);

    if ( isInteger(delay) ) {
        tr.find('td>img').first().attr('src','img/servers/enable_server.png');

    } else {

        if (delay == "bezig.") {
           tr.find('td>img').first().attr('src','img/servers/search_server.png');
        } else {
            tr.find('td>img').first().attr('src','img/servers/desable_server.png');
        }
    }   
}
```

And now the code works in both Firefox and Webkit based browsers like Google Chrome :)